# How to notate matrices (three dimensional each and size of (i x j x k) ) stored in a list?

Tags: matrices, notation

How to notate matrices (three dimensional each and size of (i x j x k) ) stored in a list, for correct journal publication?

Comment: Let $a_1,\dots a_n\in\mathbb R^{i\times j\times k}$ and put
$$L=[a_1,\dots,a_n].$$
Does it work for you?

Comment: Would matrices not be notated with bold capital letters ? Thanks